# How to get to a second DetailView in a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, detailview

Need some Help again with X-Code.
I`M building an in App Contacts List like this on Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard Contacts List]

If i press on "A" i get to the Detail Page.

If i press on "B" i get to the same Page as "A".

Same with c, D, E.....

Here is the Code i used:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PhoneA";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [PhoneBooth objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

}

I`ve tried to copy/paste from static-return cell, and changed cell to cell1, sympleTableIdentifier to sympleTableIdentifier1.

Do i need to change anything else?

The TableView works fine. All Names are in there an the DetailView shows up but its allways the same!!!!

THX for the help